# Получение длинных SMS сообщений, разбитых на части, на Android

Tags: java, android, sms

Пишу небольшое приложение, одна из функций - обработка сообщений.

Я взяла код получения sms сообщения. Всё работает, но при получении длинного sms  оно разбивается на несколько частей. Нужно собрать все части одной sms в одну строку и проверить что сообщение получено полностью.

Поиски вывели на несколько вариантов, но там создаётся массив в котором в качестве ключа используется номер отправителя, это позволяет собрать все части сообщения в одну строку, но не гарантирует получения всех частей sms.

Я изучала документацию по PDU но не смогла понять некоторые вещи.

1. Как узнать разбито ли сообщение на части?
2. Как узнать количество частей?
3. Как узнать номер части обрабатываемой прямо сейчас?

Прошу вашей помощи.

```
public class SMSMonitor extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null && ACTION.compareToIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) == 0) {
            Object[] pduArray = (Object[]) intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
            SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pduArray.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pduArray.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pduArray[i]);
            }
            StringBuilder bodyText = new StringBuilder();
            for (SmsMessage message : messages) {
                bodyText.append(message.getMessageBody());
            }
            String body = bodyText.toString();
            Observer.getInstance().send(new SmsEvent(body));
            abortBroadcast();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Кажись, тут есть то, что вам нужно: https://code.google.com/p/gtalksms/source/browse/src/com/googlecode/gtalksms/receivers/SmsReceiver.java если получится у вас к вашему коду это прикрутить - пишите в ответ - мы вас там заплюсуем.

Comment: К сожалению тут точно такая же реализация которую писала я :( Сообщения склеиваются на основании номера отправителя. Но бывает такое что длинное сообщение приходит не полностью, и тогда есть вероятность прохождения этого же сообщения второй раз но уже полностью. Я хочу выполнять через sms команды на сервере через 22/TCP порт, обидно будет если сообщение оборвётся на `rm /`

Comment: Вот тут ещё посмотрите: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7469928/3212712, но сразу говорю - я с ними дел не имел, я только гуглил.

Comment: Я поняла что нужно парсить pdu но найти актеты бит по которым определяется порядковый номер и количество пакетов я пока не могу

Comment: Сейчас приблизительно определилась с направлением раскопок интернетов. SMS PDU +UDH [вот тут](http://mobiletidings.com/2009/02/18/combining-sms-messages/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Опишу приблизительный алгоритм.
Предположим есть некая строка `pdu`:

> 07919772929090F3440B919778563412F00008519042212124618C050003F50201041D043E0447044C002C00200443043B043804460430002C00200444043E043D04300440044C002C00200430043F04420435043A0430002C000A0411043504410441043C044B0441043B0435043D043D044B0439002004380020044204430441043A043B044B043900200441043204350442002E000A04160438043204380020043504490435

где:

> 07919772929090F3 - SCA
>
> 44 - ProtocolDataUnitType
>
> 0B919778563412F0 - OriginatorAdrress
>
> 00 - ProtocolIdentifier
>
> 08 - DataCodingScheme
>
> 51904221212461 - ServiceCenterTimeStamp
>
> 8C - UserDataLength
>
> 050003F50201 - UDHI
>
> 041D043E0447044C002C00200443043B043804460430002C00200444043E043D04300440044C002C00200430043F04420435043A0430002C000A0411043504410441043C044B0441043B0435043D043D044B0439002004380020044204430441043A043B044B043900200441043204350442002E000A04160438043204380020043504490435 - UserData

так вот, то что вас интересует находится в UDHI:*050003F5**0201***

`02` - это количество сообщений, `01` - порядковый номер.
Определить, что есть *UDHI* внутри *UserData* можно по *ProtocolDataUnitType* - в нашем случае `44`(Hex). Данную `hex`-строку переведем в байт и посмотрим значение `6` бита, если он равен `1`, то тогда *UserData* содержит *UDHI*.

Надеюсь я смог Вам помочь в освоении этого непростого протокола.

Comment: Читала про PDU всю ночь, думала скончаюсь от полученных знаний, но вроде разобралась. сейчас в процессе написания статьи, уже 65000 символов набила, хочу расписать подробно и попутно наткнулась на маленькую неприятность. При конвертировании массива 16тиричных бит в строку у меня жрёт первый  ноль конструкция `String string = new BigInteger(1, (byte[]) sms[i]).toString(16)` выручайте :))

Comment: я бы с удовольствием Вам помог, но в Java не силен. Советую задать новый вопрос. А вообще где Вам потребовалось конвертация битов в строку и для чего?

Comment: Всё sms сообщение это последовательность 16тиричных бит, у меня есть массив бит sms[i], для дебага мне нужно вывести содержимое этого массива в строку с ведущими нулями, но эта конструкция вместо `07919705000F0....` выводит `7919705000F0....` =(

Comment: а зачем Вам хранить как число?! если интересно могу рассказать как сделал я, единственный нюанс я это реализовывал на C#.

Comment: Интересно было бы взглянуть если это не через цикл

Comment: [присоеденяйтесь](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/29606/discussion-between-nastya-and-bald56rus?tab=general)